# Please Tell me how to implement OSPF routing protocol

Tags: java, python, matlab, networking, ns2

Please help me by providing the code for ospf implementation(just basic implementation needed to show what ospf does). It can be any language like python(preferred),Java,c++,ns2,matlab etc.,. If I get code I can work on implementation and some modifications if I need. Please help me I'm a beginner!
And I was asked to use threads for server, client etc., and I'm confused with it. How can I use threads and implement ospf?

Comment: `ospf_ns235.patch` https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbjctSHF5TWduVFU/view?usp=sharing ... INFO https://drive.google.com/file/d/12HpasRM2y_bQEPpkSz43ilz_yMc6RoDl/view?usp=sharing ... ns2 https://groups.google.com/g/ns-users